# Trying to do seasons homework

Tags: python

So I am trying to do a seasons homework in Python by putting the Seasons and Solstice Dates in for it, but when I run it, I keep getting "Invalid" when I try putting the month and the day in. Here is my code for reference:

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

if input_month == ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June'):
    print('Spring')
elif input_month == ('June', 'July', 'August', 'September'):
    print('Summer')
elif input_month == ('September', 'October', 'November', 'December'):
    print('Autumn')
elif input_month == ('December', 'January', 'February', 'March'):
    print('Winter')
else:
    print('Invalid')

if (input_month == 'March') and (input_day < 20):
    print('Winter')
elif (input_month == 'June') and (input_day < 21):
    print('Spring')
elif (input_month == 'September') and (input_day < 22):
    print('Summer')
elif (input_month == 'December') and (input_day < 21):
    print('Autumn')
else:
    print('Invalid')
```

Comment: instead of `==` try `in` and read some python tutorials...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after the `==` to `in`, there is still a flaw: 
If you enter `March` and `10`, you will get `Spring` *and* `Winter`. Here is the fixed code:

```
input_month = input()
input_day = int(input())

if input_month in ('April', 'May'):
    print('Spring')
elif input_month in ('July', 'August'):
    print('Summer')
elif input_month in ('October', 'November'):
    print('Autumn')
elif input_month in ('January', 'February'):
    print('Winter')
if (input_month == 'March') and (input_day < 20):
    print('Winter')
elif (input_month == 'June') and (input_day < 21):
    print('Spring')
elif (input_month == 'September') and (input_day < 22):
    print('Summer')
elif (input_month == 'December') and (input_day < 21):
    print('Autumn')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string to a tuple, it will always be false. Instead you have to check if the month is inside the tuple, so use `in` instead of `==` in the first part.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the primary reason that the input isn't valid is because you are comparing the input, taken as a string, to a tuple:

```
if input_month == ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June'):
    [...]
```

That will never work. I think you want to use the `in` keyword:

```
if input_month in ('March', 'April', 'May', 'June')
```

You might also want to consider doing to input validation:

```
input_day = int(input()) # How do you know that this cast will work?
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. So far, I managed to get the month for the season to work, but for some reason the solstice day is still showing up as invalid. Is there a way to fix that as well?

Comment: @Kryptix try comparing `input_month.lower()` to `december` (all lower case). That part looks ok, I think it should work.

Comment: also don't replace `==` with `in` in the second part where you check for the solstice. In that case, `==` is the right choice.